error in python language why this errors comes
PS D:\jarvis> & C:/Python312/python.exe d:/jarvis/jarvis.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\jarvis\jarvis.py", line 34, in <module>   
    query = takecommand()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\jarvis\jarvis.py", line 15, in takecommand
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 111, in get_pyaudio
    from distutils.version import LooseVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'
PS D:\jarvis> 

please solve errors please

distutils has been removed from Python 3.12, but many modules have not caught up yet.  The easiest solution would be to uninstall 3.12 and install 3.11 instead.

Little remark to @tim-roberts answer:
See deprecation entry in the Python's What's New area.

The entire distutils package is deprecated, to be removed in Python 3.12. Its functionality for specifying package builds has already been completely replaced by third-party packages setuptools and packaging, and most other commonly used APIs are available elsewhere in the standard library (such as platform, shutil, subprocess or sysconfig).

